# using Routeparam in constant angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 app. I follow the example of @brandonroberts to restrict users from accessing page that he is not allowed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SF8gsYN1SvmUbkosHjqQ?p=preview

My problem is when I need to use the RouteParams to get the parameter from url, the injector doesn't resolve the RouteParams.

In isLoggedIn constant I need to use RouteParams to get the parameter from url
when I try let routeParams: RouteParams= injector.get(routeParams); it throws exception.

```
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';
import {Auth} from './Auth';
import {Router, ComponentInstruction,RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

export const isLoggedIn = (next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {
    let injector: Injector = appInjector(); // get the stored reference to the injector
    let auth: Auth = injector.get(Auth);
    let router: Router = injector.get(Router);

  // return a boolean or a promise that resolves a boolean
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      auth.check()
          .subscribe((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        router.navigate(['/Login']);
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                });
  });
};
```